# ethers-rs sending raw transaction to get quotes

Tags: rust, ethereum, ethers.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make an eth call to get the uniswap amountsOut and uniswapv3 quoter.

```rust
use dotenv::dotenv;
use ethers::{
    abi::{ParamType, Token},
    core::abi::decode,
    providers::{Http, Provider},
    types::{
        transaction::eip2718::TypedTransaction, Address, Bytes, NameOrAddress, TransactionRequest,
    },
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Request {
    id: String,
    to: String,
    data: String,
}

async fn latest_eth_block(rpc_endpoint: &str) -> () {
    // UniV2
    //   let eth_req = Request {
    //   id: "1".to_string(),
    //   to: "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D".to_string(),
    //   data: "0xd06ca61f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48".to_string()
    // };

    // UniV3
    let eth_req = Request {
    id: "1".to_string(),
    to: "0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6".to_string(),
    data: "0xf7729d43000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".to_string()
  };

    let client = Provider::<Http>::try_from(rpc_endpoint).unwrap();
    let tx = TypedTransaction::Legacy(TransactionRequest {
        to: Some(NameOrAddress::Address(
            Address::from_str(&eth_req.to).unwrap(),
        )),
        data: Some(Bytes::from_str(&eth_req.data).unwrap()),
        ..Default::default()
    });

    let abi_types = vec![ParamType::Uint(256), ParamType::Uint(256)];
    let call = &client.call_raw(&tx).await.unwrap();

    let decoded_values = decode(&abi_types, &call).unwrap();

    if decoded_values.len() == 2 {
        if let Token::Uint(val1) = &decoded_values[0] {
            println!("Decoded Value 1: {}", val1);
        }
        if let Token::Uint(val2) = &decoded_values[1] {
            println!("Decoded Value 2: {:?}", val2);
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    dotenv().ok();
    let rpc_http = std::env::var("RPC_HTTP").expect("RPC_HTTP must be set.");
    latest_eth_block(&rpc_http).await;
}
```

For some reason, every time I run this with UniV2 req struct I get 2 values: 32 and 2.
Also, when I try the same with a UniV3 data I get an error InvalidData

either I'm sending wrong data or decoding it wronlgy.
or i'm sending it wrongly

I also tried to do the same with web3-rs but there also no luck, error -31000 Transaction reverted.
I also tried to set the gas price and other gas related fields from the  CallRequest struct but  `{ code: ServerError(-32000), message: "both gasPrice and (maxFeePerGas or maxPriorityFeePerGas) specified", data: None })`

```rust
use ethers::abi::{ParamType, Token};
use ethers::types::U256;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use web3::helpers::decode;
use web3::types::CallRequest;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Request {
    id: String,
    to: String,
    data: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> web3::Result<()> {
    let eth_req = Request {
    id: "1".to_string(),
    to: "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D".to_string(),
    data: "0xd06ca61f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48".to_string()
  };
    let transport = web3::transports::Http::new("https://ethereum.publicnode.com").unwrap();
    let web3 = web3::Web3::new(transport);

    let call_request = CallRequest {
        to: Some(eth_req.to.parse().unwrap()),
        data: Some(eth_req.data.into()),
        // gas_price: Some(U256::from(1000)),
        // max_fee_per_gas: Some(U256::from(100000)),
        // max_priority_fee_per_gas: Some(U256::from(20333)),
        gas: Some(U256::from(27280)),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let call = web3.eth().call(call_request, None).await.unwrap();

    // let abi_types = vec![ParamType::Uint(256), ParamType::Uint(256)];
    let decoded_values: Vec<Token> = decode(call.0.as_slice().into()).unwrap();

    if decoded_values.len() == 2 {
        if let Token::Uint(val1) = &decoded_values[0] {
            println!("Decoded Value 1: {}", val1);
        }
        if let Token::Uint(val2) = &decoded_values[1] {
            println!("Decoded Value 2: {:?}", val2);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```